# trying to share git folder between mac/linux, submodules not recognized

Tags: git

I have a huge git repository that I'd like to share between my native Mac OS client and my "guest" Linux client running in a virtual machine.  I have the newest version of git built on both (1.7.12.2), and I clone the repository from Mac OS.  The issue is that in Linux, the submodules are not recognized:

```
$ git status
fatal: Not a git repository: /blah/android-wmon/.git/modules/core/modules/galaxynexus-cm10-kernel
fatal: 'git status --porcelain' failed in submodule core
```

Is sharing a git repository across these two operatings systems not possible?  I wouldn't have imagined this to be an issue.

Comment: I am sharing a repository between a physical Mac and Linux, including sub-modules with no problems. You do need to run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update` on the Linux one after you clone. Are you sure you've created the sub-module properly and pushed all the changes?

Comment: if I do "git submodule init" and "git submodule update" on the mac side, why do I need to also do it on the linux side?  It's the same exact directory shared to the virtual machine.  So I'd think that the init and update using either client would be sufficient and there'd be no need to do it twice.

Comment: OK, it wasn't quite clear from your question that both the Mac and Linux environments are pointing at the _same_ directory since the Linux one is a VM. Why don't you actually use Git to push/pull between the two? I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is achievable (sounds like it should be) and don't know why that would cause the issue you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I do "`git submodule init`" and "`git submodule update`" on the mac side, why do I need to also do it on the linux side?

Those two [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) commands are for a local repo (one you just cloned).

- `git submodule init` initializes your local configuration file, and
- `git submodule update` fetches all the data from that project and check out the appropriate commit listed in your parent repo.

Doing that in one local repo has no side-effect on any other cloned repo (like the one on your Linux, cloned from the repo on your Mac).
You need to do those commands again for your second local repo (local to your Linux server) to get all the data.

Note: make sure you did a simple `git clone`, [not a `git clone --reference`](http://randyfay.com/content/git-clone-reference-considered-harmful).

Also: make sure your submodule wasn't referenced with a full path (depending on your git version): see [this thread](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/193492):

> What are you referring to as the "last update"? v1.7.8 introduced the 
>   separate git dir for submodules, and used an absolute path.
>
> This absolute path was changed to a relative path in [this patchset](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/192173), which is present in v1.7.10-rc1.
>
> Since recently a submodule with name `<name>` has its git directory in the `.git/modules/<name>` directory of the superproject while the work tree contains a gitfile pointing there.
>   When the submodule git directory needs to be cloned because it is not found in `.git/modules/<name>` the clone command will write an absolute path into the gitfile. When no clone is necessary the git directory will be reactivated by the `git-submodule.sh` script by writing a relative path into the `gitfile`.
>
> This is inconsistent, as the behavior depends on the submodule having been cloned before into the `.git/modules of the superproject`.
>   A relative path is preferable here because it allows the superproject to be moved around
>   without invalidating the gitfile.
>   We do that by always writing the relative path into the `gitfile`, which overwrites the absolute path the clone command may have written there.

Comment: To make sure we're on the same page, I am sharing the directory with the virtual machine using VMWare's "shared folders."  So, there really is only one copy of the repository on my machine, which I am trying to access in both Mac OS and Linux.  Do you get it?  So I'm talking about the same clone.  And I can't seem to find any "full paths" in any of my git files, everything seems to be relative.

Comment: Note: git1.8.3: "git clone --reference" can now refer to a gitfile "textual symlink" that points at the real location of the repository.